# How can I log into SQL Server via SQLCMD using Git Bash?

Tags: sql-server, git-bash, sqlcmd

In my command prompt this seems working perfectly:

```
sqlcmd -S .\sqlexpress
```

But in my Git Bash this does not seem to work. It's giving:

> Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].
>   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
>   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Login timeout expired.

As I stay in my Git Bash a lot, how can I log into my SQL Server via Git Bash without moving around often?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I needed `winpty` for making login working:
`winpty sqlcmd -S .\\sqlexpress`

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the backslash separating the instance name in the git bash shell with an additional backslash:

```
SQLCMD -S .\\sqlexpress
```

Comment: my git bash now waiting forever and not returning anything

Comment: You mean the connection isn't timing out at all? Odd, it works for me. You might try `SQLCMD -S localhost\\sqlexpress`.

Comment: Hi Dan, I finally got it working: "winpty sqlcmd -S .\\sqlexpress" :)